# How can I select element that has specific value for 'abbr' attribute with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, abbr

Part of my html is :

```
<tr id="row">
  <td abbr='selectme'>
    <div>Texti inside the div</div>
    Text outside the div
  </td>

  <td>
    any others I dont care about
  <td>
</tr>
```

And I am trying to select **"Text outside the div"** which is inside the td that has attribute **'selectme'** . How can I accomplish that with jquery?

I tried like this:

```
$("#row").find("[abbr='selectme']").text()
```

but it returns nothing.

Comment: please, consider to use valide HTML, e.g, use data-* attribute. And just to be sure, is your element with ID #row unique?

Comment: That works just fine, if you have a table and valid markup.

Comment: *"...but it returns nothing."* No it doesn't, it returns all of the text in the div: http://jsbin.com/ibEZUliC/1

Comment: Check the usual suspects: script running too soon (not inside `ready()` and not at end of page), more than one element with id `row`, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) returns the text content of the descendant elements also, filter them out

```
var text = $("#row").find("[abbr='selectme']").contents().filter(function () {
    //select only text nodes of the targetted td element
    return this.nodeType == 3
}).text();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/mzWwD/)

- [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/)
- [contents()](http://api.jquery.com/contents/)
- [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)
- [nodeType](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.nodeType)

Comment: +1 , for detail explanation, it's helpful for beginners like me

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting nothing in return is probably because you you have to wrap it in a

```
$( document ).ready(function() {}); or $(function(){});
```

Because div needs to be loaded in the DOM before you reach it through jquery otherwise you are accessing an element which is not loaded yet. So by using this code:

```
$(function () {
        alert($("#row").find("[abbr='selectme']").text());
});
```

you will get the following text:
Texti inside the div
Text outside the div

Now as you want to only get the text "text outside the div" which is plain text without wrapped in any tag you have to use .contetns().filter() function and to get where the

```
nodeType === 3
```

numeric value "3" is used to get the text nodes. so you final code will look like this (I am using alert for illustration)

```
 // Shorthand for $( document ).ready()
    $(function () {
        // getting the specific text and saving into a variable
        //getting the contents of the target element
        var myText = $("#row").find("[abbr='selectme']").contents()
        // using the filter to get the text node
            .filter(function () {
                return this.nodeType === 3;
            //getting the final text
            }).text();
        alert(myText);
    });
```

Now when you run the programme you will get the output "Text outside the div".

Here is the working example http://jsfiddle.net/842nn/

Answer (score 0):

You can simply search the element by attr name:

```
$("[abbr='selectme']").text();
```